Как получить GET / POST запросы отправленные в WebView2? C# WPF
Пишу приложение которое должно получать отправленные сайтом (открытым в WebView2) POST / GET запросы, и в последствии получать заголовки / ответы этих запросов.
Я попытался реализовать это через эвенты, но безуспешно:
await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
webView.CoreWebView2.GetDevToolsProtocolEventReceiver("Network.responseReceived").DevToolsProtocolEventReceived += (sender, e) 
    => Title = e.ParameterObjectAsJson;

Конечно можно вызвать DevTools окно, но это не то что мне надо

О том, как работать с запросами, написано весьма подробно в документации, даже пример есть, который отлично работает. Внимание на AddWebResourceRequestedFilter и WebResourceRequested.
